# How do I switch to Linux (Ubuntu) on Chromebook?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, chrome-book

For reference, the Chromebook model is `SNOW FREMONT A-E 0878`

I used `Crouton` to install `Ubuntu`  on my `Chromebook`. In doing so, I had my computer in *developer mode* and wasn't able to save anything that was on my computer prior to doing so. As a result, I switched back to `Chrome OS` with the command `Ctrl+Alt+Forward/Back` to try and download a python script I was interested in playing around with from my class. I signed into my Google account, and from then on I haven't been able to access `Ubuntu`.

I tried putting the computer in `recovery mode` again and going through the steps once more (albeit I see it as a wasted effort since it's already ON my computer, but I digress).

Since trying to put it in recovery mode, I'm left with the yellow exclamation mark saying `Chrome OS is missing or damaged`; I put in the USB I used originally when going through the entire process. Another screen shows up that says `the device I inserted does not contain Chrome OS` (no duh). `Ctrl+D` is the next attempt, but to no prevail as I'm stuck with the yellow exclamation mark.

Comment: Have you gone through the [steps listed on the Chromebook help site](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en)?  Worked for me fine when I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### If you can sign in to your Chromebook, try these steps first:

1. Turn your Chromebook off, then back on again.
2. If your Chromebook still has an error, [reset to factory settings](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084).

#### If this doesn't work, on the working computer (not the Chromebook with the error):

1. If you're using a Mac or PC:

   1. If you haven't yet, install Chrome.
   2. Open Chrome Chrome.
   3. Install the recovery app.
2. Open the recovery app.
3. Click Get started.
4. Click Select a model from a list, or type in the model number of the Chromebook you want to recover. To find this number, look at the bottom of the error message on your Chromebook screen.
5. Click Continue.
6. Insert your USB flash drive or SD card into the computer.
7. In the dropdown menu, choose the USB flash drive or SD card you inserted.
8. Click Continue.
9. Click Create now.
10. When you see a message saying that your recovery media is ready, remove the USB flash drive or SD card from the computer.

#### On the Chromebook with the error:

1. If you have anything connected to this Chromebook (such as a mouse or external hard drive), remove it.
2. Enter recovery mode:

   - Chromebook: Press and hold Esc + Refresh, then press Power. Let go of Power. When a message shows on the screen, let go of the other keys.
3. You'll see one of these messages:

> Chrome OS is missing or damaged.
>
> Please insert a recovery USB stick or SD card.

4. Insert the USB flash drive or SD card that you used to create recovery media.
   Follow the on-screen instructions.

---

Source: [Recover your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en).